# Providing an API for Cancel(QueryID) i.e. Cancel long running query through JDBC in RESTful service

Tags: java, rest, jdbc

We went through few blogs on internet, which suggested to use 
Statement.close() method.

Our scenario : We have developed RESTful service. We execute an SQL query through JDBC framework behind an API call. i.e. When an API request lands on our RESTful server, behind the scene, we acquire a JDBC Connection from the connection pool that we have maintained, and in the same connection, we follow normal JDBC steps of executing Query. e.g.

```
Connection connection;
Statement statement;
ResultSet resultSet; 
try{
   connection = connectionPool.getConnection();
   statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
   resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
catch(SQLException){
 // do something
}
finally{
   resultSet.close();
   statement.close();
   connection.close();
}
```

Few queries takes time to get the response.

Our Requirement : If query executed in one HTTP RESTful service is consuming a considerable time, we want to provide another API using which , long running query can be terminated, thus, resources on backend datastore as well as on the REST server i.e. Connection will be free.

We are looking for an approach exactly same as providing Cancel(QueryID) API publicly to allowed users. Would persisting statement instances for cancelling queries in another API call be right approach?

Comment: Probably the same problem was discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201761/handling-long-queries-without-violating-rest?rq=1

Comment: So you want to provide something like "Cancel(QueryID)" publicly? Or just time out the rest call and cancel the SQL-Query and clean up if a certain duration is hit?

Comment: Hi, You may setup a query timeout for your query and the underlying architecture handle the SQL Exception thrown. This whay you can resolve if the request will be forwarded for another RestfulWS or an error will be thrown.

Comment: You could return a `202 Accepted` status code along with some identifier of your query. Then provide an endpoint that receives the identifier of the query and cancels it Another endpoint could be user to get the result of the query.

Comment: @Fildor Yes. I am looking for an approach exactly same as providing Cancel(QueryID) publicly to allowed users.  @ SergeiPodlipaev The scenario mentioned is different than the link referenced.

Comment: I second Cassio's approach. You'll have to return some kind of handle which leads you to end up with 3 functions: 1: Start query and get back an identifier 2: Request the result of the query (using the identifier) or 3: Cancel the query using the identifier.